# ImportError: cannot import name init_printing

Tags: python, import, anaconda, sympy

When I try to import :

```
from sympy import init_printing
```

or

```
from sympy import *
```

I get the same error:

[image: Sympy Error]

I'm using Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 and I'vre already installed SymPy

Comment: If you called a file `sympy.py`, pick a different name. Also, when posting error messages, post the whole thing, including the stack trace, and as code-formatted text, not an image.

Comment: Sorry for that, my file name is not sympy. I will try to improve this question. Thank you